# Type from Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, typechecking

Suppose that I have:

```
trait A

class B extends A
```

compiled into class files.
Later I load those using reflection:

```
val a = Class forName "A"
val b = Class forName "B"
```

Could anyone tell me how to check whether `b` is the subtype of `a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `isAssignableFrom` method in `Class`:

```
a isAssignableFrom b
```

This returns `true` if `b` is a subclass/subinterface of `a` or `b == a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the `getInterfaces` method on `b` and iterate through the array to see if any of them equals `a`.

Comment: Thank you, too simple and I didn't think of.